# Вывод названия типа произвольной записи

Tags: php, wordpress

В функции `register_post_type` в массиве параметров есть массив `labels`, а у него свойство `'name'`, задающее основное название для типа записи. Можно ли как-то это название выводить в шаблоне, находясь в архиве какого либо типа записей?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `get_queried_object` на странице архива записей возвращает объект поста (`WP_Post_Type`), к свойству `labels` которого можно обратиться:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object(); 
$labels = $queried_object->labels;
echo $labels->name; // выведет название типа записи
```